# Express 404: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: javascript, express

I am working on a Node/Express app and I would like it to return a 404 page if a promise function does not resolve.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
app.get("/projects", t("projects", function(req, res) {
    res.header("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store");
    return projects.list(req.user, req.query)
        .then((projects) => (Object.assign(projects, { company_name: req.user.company_name })))
        .catch(() => res.status("404").send(""));
}));
```

Unfortunately this crashes my app with the error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

How can I make this so it 404s without crashing the app, if and only if the promise rejects?

For the record, the `projects.list` function is very simple, it just makes a database call and returns an object.

```
function list(user, query_params) {
    const folder = query_params.folder || "all";
    return entity.User.listedProjects(user.id, filter_by)
        .then((projects) => {
            if (folder !== null && !projects.some(t => t.current)) {
                return Promise.reject();
            }
            return {
                "projects": projects,
                "active_folder": folder
            };
        });
}
```

UPDATE: as requested, here's the `t` function:

```
function t(template_name, get_additional_params, options={}) {
    return function(req, res) {
        if (!req.user && !options.do_not_require_login) return res.redirect("/login?redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(req.originalUrl));

        if (!get_additional_params) {
            get_additional_params = (() => Promise.resolve({}));
        }

        get_additional_params(req, res)
            .then(function(additional_params) {
                if (additional_params && "_redirect" in additional_params) {
                    return res.redirect(additional_params._redirect);
                }

                const standard_params = {
                    "error": req.flash("error"),
                };

                const params = Object.assign({}, additional_params, standard_params);
                res.render(template_name + ".html", params);
            })
            .catch(utils.fail(req, res));
    };
}
```

Comment: What’s #t that you are resolving for the express callback?

Comment: We need to see the `t()` function's code.  You only send one response in this code and that's when there's an error.  So, we need to see the rest of the code that sends a response.  As others have said, your `.catch()` does not rethrow so you're returning a resolve promise which `t()` is probably using to try to send another response.

Answer (score 1):

`.catch(...)` results in resolved promise so probably within your `t` function you're trying to send additional headers.

as a quick fix you can replace your catch with

```
.catch(err => {
  res.status("404").send("");
  throw err;
});
```

and your `t` function won't try to set additional headers

Comment: thanks! this doesn't help unfortunately, I've updated the question to show what the `t` function does.

Answer (score -2):

```
app.get("/projects", t("projects", function(req, res) {

return projects.list(req.user, req.query)
    .then((projects) => (Object.assign(projects, { company_name: req.user.company_name })))
    .then(() => res.header("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store"))
    .catch(() => res.status("404").send(""));
}));
```

Comment: Please type an explanation along with code or you will always be downvoted heavily.